# Button payload / callback?

Tags: google-hangouts

I want to be able to reply to a user with my bot based on a button they pressed. So far, the only property I can find for button.onClick is "openUrl", but it doesn't seem possible to assign the button a value or a payload / callback URL. Additionally, there is no "Button Tapped" event.

How can I use buttons to allow my user to interact with my bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to add a button response to Hangouts Chat. The primary one seems to be via using Cards with either KeyValue, or ActionResponse.

https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick

You can use:

1. buttons.onClick.parameters.keyValue to pass unique Parameters
2. textButton.onClick.openLink to open a link with a text button
3. ActionResponse to update a card with a custom card when a Click event occurs.

Comment: Absolutely right, seems like the guide was more useful than the full reference... Thanks.